# External URL is not opening/unable to open in MS Teams in group chat

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

External URL is not opening in MS Teams group chat if application logout from MS Teams.
Even i have added bot into a group chat already then able to post the adaptive card details to bot section., but unable to open the existing open button until & unless adding a bot again into a group chat.
please check the image below.[image]

Comment: Could you please explain the issue a little more and share repro steps?

Comment: are you looking for displaying the webpage by clicking `open`?

Comment: @GauravGupta i'm opening a popup based Open button click

Comment: so what happens when you click? Are you handling the click in the code using `async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItem(...)` ?

Comment: @GauravGupta   can you please tell me what type i should use for custom popup., when i click the OPEN button...

Comment: @GauravGupta handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItem nothing is happening....

Comment: @sivasubramanian, please have a look on the answer, does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the popup window, you can run your own custom HTML/JavaScript code.

To open a popup window you have to include "msteams":{"type":"task/fetch"} into "data" object of the action object of the card. I used AdaptiveCardDesigner to create an example for you. But i think it's not necessary to use Adaptive Cards to achieve this, this should work with HeroCards too.

So here's an example:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Request Task"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Open Task Window",
            "data": {
                "msteams": {
                    "type": "task/fetch"
                },
                "messageId": "12345"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

The next step is to handle this request on the backend and reply with an URL for the TaskModule window.

```
async handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch(context, action) {
    return {
        task: {
            type: 'continue',
            value: {
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                title: 'My Webpage',
                url: `https://mywebpage.com`
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Note: make sure to include the URL of the page in the `validDomains` section of manifest file**

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios

1. If the button is just opening a URL in browser, the adaptive card action should be as this

```
"actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "View",
            "url": "https://stackoverflow.com"
        }
```

2. If the button is of type "signin", which opens the URL in teams as a new window, the domain should be added to the `validDomains` section. The teamsApp manifest should have your external URL as a valid domain

```
 "validDomains": [
      "token.botframework.com",
      "<<your-domain>>"
    ]
```